# Writing a DLL in C (without C++)

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I want to write a DLL with Visual Studio and by default all tutorials or templates include C++ (.cpp file).

If I try to create a DLL project without a precompiled header, the generated project only has a "dllmain.cpp" file (which is optional according to the Microsoft site).

So I deleted the file "dllmain.cpp" just to have MyDLL.c and MyDLL.h. So I tried to have a project as pure as possible by :

- removing the includes "pch.h", utility, limits.h
- deleting the extern "C" code in the include before the declaration of my prototype

So I at the end, the code I have look like :

MyDLL.h :

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL_API
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_API void dll_init(void);
```

MyDLL.c :

```
#include "MyDLL.h"
#include <stdio.h>


void dll_init(void)
{
    printf("------- Init DLL -------");
}
```

It compiles but I just get the warning : "warning C4273 : inconsistent DLL linkage".
Error I can fix by forcing :
`"#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)"`

Is it really possible to write a DLL in C only. Or the use in C++ is mandatory and it is the use of `extern "C"` that allows to wrap in C. What is the philosophy?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why you can't write a DLL in C.  But `#ifdef DLL_API` looks wrong to me, I'd double-check that.

Comment: It is definitively possible. I did it many years ago, unfortunately I cannot share anything.

Comment: Removing `extern "C"` is problematic if the library would get used from C++ – better is to *conditionally* (de)activate it: `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif /* declarations */ #ifdef __cplusplus } #endif`. Then your header is usable from both C++ and C.

Comment: In addition to Paul's comment: You might need to `#define DLL_API` before `#include "MyDLL.h"` in your implementation source. However, the name of the macro looks wrong, because you would need to `#undef` it before redefinition.

Comment: Pure technically using the same symbol name in this case *is* legal *provided* you `#undef` it before re-defining it (which you don't, though). If *good practice* is a different question, though. In any case you need to make sure that `DLL_API` indeed *already is* defined when `#including` the header. You can do so by `#define` within the C file *before* including the header or via compiler flags for the file or global ones!

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback.
Sorry, I did make an error "#ifdef DLL_API" but I understood that in my case, I could force it to "__declspec(dllexport)" since the library will be used in another application.

For the use of extern "C", my code does not compile anymore if I add this directive to the exported function. I get a lot of error codes if I do that.
This directive is new for me but if my DLL is written in C, I should not need to use it, right? Would it be ok if my code was in C++?

Answer (score 1):

At first: You can write both C++ and C compatible header by *conditionally* providing the `extern "C"` flag:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

DLL_API void dll_init(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This is a standard pattern that profiting from the fact that `__cplusplus` is only defined by a C++ compiler.

Then you need to make sure your compiler definitions are setup correctly; to make them legal, you at very least need to undefine them before re-defining:

```
#ifdef DLL_API
#undef DLL_API                              // <-- (!)
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

If it is good practice to use the same symbol name for different purposes is questionable, though. You might consider renaming one of those two.

Then for compiling the DLL source file you need to make sure that DLL_API already *is* defined *before* you include the header. This can occur e.g. by defining it before the include (but you need to do so *everywhere* you include the header within your library):

```
#define DLL_API 1
#include "mydll.h"
```

Alternatively you might define `DLL_API` via the IDE settings (not sure where that needs to be done in MSVC – not using that one, so you need to look up on your own).

An alternative pattern might look as follows:

```
//include/mydll.h
#ifndef DLL_API
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//source/mydll.h:
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include <include/mydll.h>

// any DLL source (assuming placed within source folder):
#include "mydll.h"
```

Better? You trade the `#define`/`#undef` trouble or the additional pre-processor symbol for an additional header. Good idea to use the same file name? Rename the internal/private one to your needs, it's not about naming conventions, it's about the pattern...

Background `extern "C"`:

C and C++ use different function name patterns; C++ supports function *overloading* and the real function names get prefixes by which the function signatures can get identified (name mangling!).

So if you have two functions

```
void f(int i);
void f(int i, double d);
```

true function names as found in the compiled library/executable  might actually look (transparent to you!) like `i_f` and `id_f` (only exemplary, true mangling rules you find [here](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)).

With `extern "C"` you now tell the C++ compiler that functions you load from a library need to be looked up *without* name mangling, just as a C compiler would do – and that functions to be compiled in your project should be compiled without applying name mangling.

By telling the C++ compiler to do so, though, you lose the ability to use C++ features in the signature of the function like overloading, namespaces, etc. (not that you could not use C++ features *inside* the function, but in the signatures no way...).

Comment: Thank you for this information.
I know that my #ifdef DLL_API was incorrect. The source of my confusion was the Microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)
They explain that Visual Studio sets <PROJECTNAME>_EXPORTS at the time the DLL project is generated but I may have misunderstood...

I will try to continue my project with the DLL but the way VS generates the DLL template and the errors I got led me to believe that you can't really develop a DLL in C++. I will continue.